# Buscador 3 campos diferentes de 3 tablas diferentes

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo 3 tablas , Comics(id, Nombre, numero...), Autores(id, nombre...) y Dibujantes( id, nombre...), lo que quiero hacer es una consulta ( para un buscador ) que si le digo que me busque la palabra "Batman" me muestre si hay coincidencias en los nombre de ambas 3 tablas .

Tengo esto, que he ido encontrando por intenert, pero me da un fallo en el `Join`, y no consigo averiguar por que.

Gracias y saludos.

PD: A ver si lo explico bien. Intento utilizar el ORM para que cuando en el programa hagan una busqueda con una palabra me lo compare con 3 campos diferentes y si hay alguna coincidendia me devuelva un objeto.

```
  ComictecaEntities mo = new ComictecaEntities();

     String[] titulos = { "hola", "hola", "hola" };

     DbSqlQuery<Comics> nop = mo.Comics.Join(mo.Comics,
        Comics => Comics.Comic_id,
        Autores => Autores.Autor_id,
        Dibujantes => Dibujantes.Dibujante_id,
        (Comics) => new { Comics, Autores, Dibujantes }).Where(fullEntry => fullEntry.Comics.Titulo == "hola");
```

Comment: "ambas 3 tablas" xDD Bienvenido a SOes

Comment: *me da un fallo en el Join*: ¿puedes ser mas específico por favor? También, ayúdanos a reproducir tu problema: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: debes realizar el where para cada una de las entidades.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo en las tablas, no tienen campos por los que hacer el join.

Yo haría algo así:

```
var items = from c in Comics
join a in Autores on c.id_autor equals a.id
join d in Dibujantes on c.id_dibujante equals d.id
where a.Nombre.Contains("Batman") || a.Nombre.Contains("Batman") || d.Nombre.Contains("Batman");
```

Yo he establecido que la relación entre cómics y autores y entre cómics y dibujantes es n a 1 si no, habría que hacer una tabla de relación.

Espero te sirva.